# Make range with only first and last number? Java?

Tags: java

I have to get input for a certain number of days and a starting number. With that, the number of days gets split in half, in first half starting number decremented by 2. Last half incremented by 1. If days is uneven, last half has one more day. Heres what I have:

```
int days;
int num;
int 1half;
int 2half;
int new_num;

System.out.print("Enter number of days: ");
days = keyboard.nextInt();   

System.out.print("Enter number of first day: ");   
num = keyboard.nextInt();

int half = days/2;
if (days %2 == 0){
    1half = (half);
    2half = (half);
} else {
    1half = (half); 
    2half = (half) + 1;
}

int first_half[] = {1,(half)};
int last_half[] = {((half)+1), days};
while (1half > 1 || 1half < half) {
    new_temp = temp - 2;
    System.out.println("Day \t Num");
    System.out.println(new_num);
    first_half--;
}

while(2half >= (half + 1) && (2half <= days)) {
    new_temp = temp++;
    System.out.println("Day \t Num");
    System.out.println(new_num);
    last_half--;
}
```

Im stuck now though.
If you see anything Id be happy to hear about it. I just need some help/advice. I'll clarify anything if this is hard to understand. Thank you in advance

Edit:
The final output should look something like this:

```
Day Num
1 -10
2 -12
3 -14
4 -16
5 -18
6 -17
7 -16
8 -15
9 -14
10 -13
11 -12
```

If this makes sense.

Heres my output:

```
Day      Temperature
8
Day      Temperature
8
Day      Temperature
8
Day      Temperature
```

continues forever

Comment: Can you provide insight on what the current code is producing? It speeds things along for us.

Comment: Sorry about that. I put a "ideal output" in the edit

Comment: As @Peter asked, what is the output of your current code? Also, what are you using the arrays for?

Comment: It prints the Day Num, then it just keeps repeating the number 8 endlessly? For the array, I figured I needed to make a range for all the days since I want to print each day number.

Comment: Wow you know your homework sucks when no one can do it :(

Comment: It's not so bad. I would put your exact output into the question. It looks like in your while loops you're using the array as the condition (first_half > 1) and then decrementing the array as well (first_half--)

Comment: I actually realized I typed the code wrong here(not that it made a difference) but its fixed now. I thought i was terminating the infinite loop with the (1half--) but apparently it didnt do anything. I think the major problem is this (int first_half[] = {1,(half)};) How do I make a range that has all the numbers from 1 to half the days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why do you need those arrays and other stuff, but you may have a look at my code. It produces exactly what you want.

```
        int days = 11;
        int num = -10;
        int output = num + 2;
        System.out.println("Day \t Num");
        int half = days / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= half; i++) {
            output -= 2;
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + output);
        }
        for (int i = half + 1; i <= days; i++) {
            output++;
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + output);
        }
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE REAL MVP! THIS WIZARD! I dont know what I was thinking....But do you mind explaining what the (int i) and output stuff is? What does it represent?

Comment: `output` is your number that changes for every day. `i` is an iterator on `for` loop which represents your current day. two loops for two halfs. Inside first loop `output` decrements by 2 every time, inside the another - increments by one, as you need. Read more about loops in java. Good luck in learning java.

Comment: Why did you put num + 2 as ouput? What does the 2 do? What if i were to put in any value as num? Would this still work? Thanks~

Comment: @vee it is to avoid shifting on numbers since I subtract 2 **before** printing it. Without it, i.e. `int output = num`, first output will be `-12` and not `-10`. There are several ways to avoid this shift - we can add 2 after the first loop for example. Test this code, change it, change values and you'll understand it better :)

Comment: Thank you so much I actually understand it now~

Answer (score 0):

Your endless loop is caused by your condition statement of your while:

`while (1half > 1 || 1half < half)`.

If 1half is set to be any number greater than 1 then this will loop forever. You probably want to use an `&&` instead of an `||` as well. But don't see anything in the body of the loop that would affect things to make it get out of the loop.